# Using css transform property in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can you specify cross-browser transform controls using jQuery since each browser seems to use its own methodology?

Here is the code I am using for Firefox but I can't even get it to work. I think it's because there is no way to tell which transformation – scale, rotate, skew – to use.

```
$(".oSlider-rotate").slider({
     min: 10,
     max: 74,
     step: .01,
     value: 24,
     slide: function(e,ui){
                 $('.user-text').css('transform', ui.value)

            }                
  });
```

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery CSS Hooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you want to use a specific transform function, then all you need to do is include that function in the value. For example:

```
$('.user-text').css('transform', 'scale(' + ui.value + ')');
```

Secondly, browser support is getting better, but you'll probably still need to use vendor prefixes like so:

```
$('.user-text').css({
  '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(' + ui.value + ')',
  '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(' + ui.value + ')',
  '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(' + ui.value + ')',
  '-o-transform'      : 'scale(' + ui.value + ')',
  'transform'         : 'scale(' + ui.value + ')'
});
```

jsFiddle with example: http://jsfiddle.net/jehka/230/

Comment: That only affects IE, which we're not targeting anyway :p

Comment: Clarification: The OP wrote **cross browser** transform.

Comment: Removing the comma doesn't make it fully cross browser, neither the `-moz` nor `-webkit` vendor prefixes apply to IE. My code serves as an example of *how* to apply the properties. If you don't like it, feel free to write your own answer :)

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5139395/1195891) explains that the extra comma is against ES5 spec with regards to cross-browser syntax. Just sayin. :p

Comment: That answer shows that a trailing comma *is* valid in the ES5 spec.

Comment: As stated it depends in what manner, but it's your decision nontheless.

Comment: Simply put, the [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5139232/1195891) accepted answer of that question states big trouble for IE browsers. The OP here wanted a cross-browser solution which is why I downvoted you since you wrote that it's going to be an issue only in IE browsers for which you do not want to target. I never intended to write an answer here, only enlighten you of a syntax error.

Answer (score 8):

Setting a `-vendor` prefix that isn't supported in older browsers can cause them to throw an exception with `.css`. Instead detect the supported prefix first:

```
// Start with a fall back
var newCss = { 'zoom' : ui.value };

// Replace with transform, if supported
if('WebkitTransform' in document.body.style) 
{
    newCss = { '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + ui.value + ')'};
}
// repeat for supported browsers
else if('transform' in document.body.style) 
{
    newCss = { 'transform': 'scale(' + ui.value + ')'};
}

// Set the CSS
$('.user-text').css(newCss)
```

That works in old browsers. I've done `scale` here but you could replace it with whatever other transform you wanted.

Comment: I noticed that the property starts with lower case 'w' -> ie 'webkitTransform' but it works with upper case anyhow, somehow

Comment: @PandaWood both properties exist

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jquery, jquery.transit is very simple and powerful lib that allows you to make your transformation while handling cross-browser compability for you.
It can be as simple as this : `$("#element").transition({x:'90px'})`.

Take it from this link : http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score 1):

I started using the 'prefix-free' Script available at [http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) so I don't have to take care about the vendor prefixes. It neatly takes care of setting the correct vendor prefix behind the scenes for you. Plus a jQuery Plugin is available as well so one can still use jQuery's .css() method without code changes, so the suggested line in combination with prefix-free would be all you need:

```
$('.user-text').css('transform', 'scale(' + ui.value + ')');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".oSlider-rotate").slider({
     min: 10,
     max: 74,
     step: .01,
     value: 24,
     slide: function(e,ui){
                 $('.user-text').css('transform', 'scale(' + ui.value + ')')

            }                
  });
```

This will solve the issue

Comment: Thank you participating at stackoverflow. Please add some explanation to your answer to make it useful for others.