# Object Oriented Javascript code not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, oop, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code.

```
function radioButtons() {

var _inputCount;
var _inputParentCount;
var _radioInput;

return {

    inputCounter:function(groupId){

        _inputCount = $(groupId).find("input");
        _inputParentCount = $(_inputCount).parent();

        for(i = 0; i < _inputParentCount.length; i++){
            $(_inputParentCount[i]).attr("id", groupId + [i]);
        }

    },

    radioAction:function(radioButton){

        _radioInput = $(radioButton).find("input");

        for(i = 0; i < _inputCount.length; i ++){

            $(_inputCount[i]).parent().removeClass("selected");
            $(_inputCount[i]).attr("value", "false");

        }


        $(radioButton).addClass("selected");
        $(_radioInput).attr("value", "true");
    },



};
};

var radioButtonsOne = new radioButtons();

$(document).ready(function(){
radioButtonsOne.inputCounter("#radioButtonsGroup");
});
```

Its a custom function I wrote for custom Radio buttons. I have a similar one for Checkboxes buttons. It works perfectly in all browsers except for IE7. It tells me that `radioButtonsOne` is not defined. But it is though. Any idea why?

Thank!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139205/javascript-can-a-comma-occur-after-the-last-set-of-values-in-an-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
  $(radioButton).addClass("selected");
        $(_radioInput).attr("value", "true");
    },
```

remove the `,`

```
  $(radioButton).addClass("selected");
        $(_radioInput).attr("value", "true");
    }
```

Comment: Nice! In fact, IE7 throws an exception when the last key of an object is followed by a comma.