# $tree.tree is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, plone

I am generating a tree in plone using an add-on product called `collective.virtualtreecategories` . However, I keep getting a weird javascript error and the tree cannot be displayed.

On my browser's error console, I get the following:

```
$tree.tree is not a function
```

Here is the part of code that produces the error:

```
$tree.tree({
    data: {
        type: "json",
        url: "@@vtc-categories-tree.json",
        async: false
    },
    lang: {
        new_node: "New category"
    },
    rules: {
        deletable: ["folder"],
        renameable: ["folder"],
        draggable: "none",
        droppable: "none",
    },
    callback: {
        beforechange: function(node, tree_obj) {
            return before_change_node()
        },
        onselect: function(node, tree_obj) {
            node_selected(node)
        },
        oncreate: function(node) {
            jq(node).attr('rel', 'folder')
        },
        onrename: function(node, lang, tree_obj, rb) {
            old_id = node.id // may be undefined (new node)
            new_name = jq(node).children("a:visible").text();
            // shared code. Server determines if creating/renaming by the old_name value
            jq.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "vtc-category-added-renamed",
                data: {
                    'category_path': selected_category(node),
                    'old_id': old_id,
                    'new_name': new_name
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    jq.jGrowl(data.msg, {
                        life: 1500
                    });
                    // set/change node id
                    if (data.result) {
                        node.id = data.new_id
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                traditional: true
            })
        },
        beforedelete: function(node, tree_obj) {
            jq.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "vtc-category-removed",
                data: {
                    'category_path': selected_category(node)
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    jq.jGrowl(data.msg, {
                        life: 3000
                    });
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                traditional: true
            });
            return true;
        }
    }
});​
```

The complete code listing can be found [HERE](https://github.com/collective/collective.virtualtreecategories/blob/master/src/collective/virtualtreecategories/browser/resources/virtualtreecategories-controlpanel.js)

Can someone help me fix this?

**UPDATE:** 
I should perhaps add that, this was working before in a different setting. Now, I just recreated the project and thats when I got this error.

Comment: Did you include a jQuery "tree" plugin?  *Before* running this script?

Comment: what sort of object is $tree? The problem is as the message suggests that `$tree` doesn't have a function `tree` on it. This suggests that $tree is not the object you think it is or that you are not calling something you should be further up. So examine `$tree` to find out what it is and make sure it definitely should have a `tree` function on it.

Comment: @Chris: According to the link, `$tree` is a jQuery object.

Comment: @cHao: true enough. So yeah, the problem is that nothing has defined that function on the jQuery object by the looks of things. I guess that is what the "tree plugin" you mentioned would be expected to do.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your code `$tree` isn't a function, its an element
on line 89  `var $tree = jq('ul#VTCTree');`

therefore I assume `.tree()` is a JQuery widget and isn't working as expected?

Just seen some of the comments and the updates.  Have you checked the path/file inclusion of the tree plugin/widget?

Comment: @Frankline have you got a link to the plugin?

Comment: Yes, I have included it on my question below the code. This is how it should look like: [Plugin Product](http://plone.org/products/collective.virtualtreecategories/)

Answer (score 0):

> On my browser's error console, I get the following:

if your browser is Internet Explorer, the extra comma that you have here

`droppable: "none",`

is a widely known problem.

Not a problem for Firefox, but will give unexpected results, like 3 elements in the following array. but length = 4

`myArr = [1,2,3,,]`

also, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5139232/982924

Comment: No, I'm on Linux. This was working before both in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, even though I had jquery loaded and the jquery.filetree.min plugin loaded. I was missing the jquery UI js which is also required.