# List of multiple products into php datalayer

Tags: php, smarty, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, oxid

I would like to get a nice data layer tracking for my site's marketing pixels in the "order confirmation page" (thank you for you purchase page).
The site uses OXID Shop as the ecommerce platform.

I would like to have the following setup:

```
IF currentPage == 'thankyou':

products_info = '[{id: 'product_id_1', price: 'price_1', quantity: 'quantity_1'},
                  {id: 'product_id_2', price: 'price_2', quantity: 'quantity_2'}]'
```

I am trying the following code to obtain the values directly from the backend if my page variable "CurrentController"='thankyou', which I can easily do for a variable that contains only the values of one article.

**Example:**

```
[{if $currentControllerName == "thankyou"}]    

    var dataLayer = [];

    [{assign var="order" value=$oView->getOrder()}]

    dataLayer.push(
                   {email: [{$order->oxorder__oxbillemail->value}]}
                   );

[{/if}]
```

The issue is when I need to get values for more than one article, something like what I mentioned at the beginning for the products_info variable.

I am trying the following code, but I'm not sure how to make the iterator "append" or send each products values to one single variable:

```
[{if $currentControllerName == "thankyou"}]    

var dataLayer = [];

[{assign var="order" value=$oView->getOrder()}]

(
[{foreach from=$orderArticles item="currOrderArticle"}]
[{assign var="currArticle" value=$currOrderArticle->getArticle()}]
[{assign var="currBasePrice" value=$currOrderArticle->getBasePrice()}]

product_info: [{id: [{$currOrderArticle->oxorderarticles__oxartnum->value}], 
                price: [{$currBasePrice->getBruttoPrice()}], 
                quantity: [{$currOrderArticle->oxorderarticles__oxamount->value}]}]


[{/foreach}]
)

[{/if}]
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to archieve, but OXID is using smarty as a template language and you can use Smarty's capture to append output to one single variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javascript function .push() that you are calling appends an item to your dataLayer Array every time you call it. (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push))

So why not let smarty render the the call to that function for every product that was in the basket.

```
[{if $oView->getClassName() == "thankyou"}]

<script>

        var dataLayer = [];

        [{assign var="basket" value=$oView->getBasket()}]

        [{foreach from=$basket->getContents() item=basketitem}]

            [{assign var=itemarticle value=$basketitem->getArticle()}]
            [{assign var="basketitemprice" value=$basketitem->getPrice()}]

            dataLayer.push({ id: [{$itemarticle->oxarticles__oxartnum->value}], price: [{$basketitemprice->getBruttoPrice()}], quantity: [{$basketitem->getAmount()}] });

        [{/foreach}]

</script>

[{/if}]
```

This will add your products to your Javascript `dataLayer` Array.

It's worthy to note that the following should also work: (might [break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036618/does-internet-explorer-9-choke-on-extra-commas-at-the-end-of-array-and-object-li) in unsupported version of IE)

```
[{if $oView->getClassName() == "thankyou"}]

<script>

    var dataLayer = [

        [{assign var="basket" value=$oView->getBasket()}]

        [{foreach from=$basket->getContents() item=basketitem}]

            [{assign var=itemarticle value=$basketitem->getArticle()}]
            [{assign var="basketitemprice" value=$basketitem->getPrice()}]

            { id: [{$itemarticle->oxarticles__oxartnum->value}], price: [{$basketitemprice->getBruttoPrice()}], quantity: [{$basketitem->getAmount()}] },

        [{/foreach}]

    ];

</script>

[{/if}]
```

In the end what you are trying to do is creating a Javascript Array (that can be read by Google Tag Manager). This is the final output (and perfectly valid Javascript) on the Thankyou page:

```
<script>

    var dataLayer = [];

    dataLayer.push({ id: 3788, price: 24.95, quantity: 1 });           
    dataLayer.push({ id: 1401, price: 129, quantity: 1 });        
    dataLayer.push({ id: 10101, price: 0, quantity: 1 });

</script>
```

Note that you are not using PHP to append the data to the dataLayer variable. You are creating Javascript Code (with Smarty/PHP) that will then create the dataLayer Array (that can then be utilized by Google Tag Managers Javascript)